# pd.read_csv - epoch date conversion

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have csv with date columns, `Bill Date` for example, stored as the Excel serial number for the date. So 12/15/2017 is represented in the csv as 43084. I need to convert this in my DataFrame to an actual date Pandas / Python recognizes. So, my question: Is there a more efficient method than what I've used to convert the dates?

```
df:
    Bill Date
0       43084
```

Excel stores dates as days since Jan 1, 1900 and pandas defaults to Jan 1, 1970.

```
diff = pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01') - pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01')
pd.to_datetime([43084 - (diff.days + 2)], unit='d')

DatetimeIndex(['2017-12-15'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

So, am I missing something obvious here (e.g., an option for a different origin)?

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
 import pandas as pd
 from datetime import datetime

 df = pd.read_csv("yourdataframe.csv")
 df["Bill_Date"] = df["Bill_Date"].map(lambda x: datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + x - 2))
 df["Bill_Date"] = df["Bill_Date"].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

 print df.head()
```

Comment: Thanks, the method I've used is actually faster though. So, I'm not sure this is any more efficient.

Comment: Have you calculated the time this way takes on your data?

Comment: Also, I thought you have asked for the functionality not speed. Anyways, it's good that your method is working fine and faster. Good luck with your code.

Comment: %%timeit
df["Bill_Date"].map(lambda x: datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + x - 2)) ....73.4 µs ± 3.04 µs per loop

Comment: %%timeit
pd.to_datetime(df['Bill_Date'].values - (diff.days + 2), unit='d') .....47.2 µs ± 2.12 µs per loop

Comment: Dude,you can calculate this value earlier: datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() and use it as val+x-2, the time I guess would reduce. Anyways, thanks for pointing out.